# mysql select data from multiple tables with sum and average

Tags: mysql, sql, select, multiple-tables

I have a tables like below :

Table1: purchase

```
Code  Item   pur_qty
01    Chair  02
02    Table  03
03    Board  01
```

Table2: purchase_return

```
Code  Item   pur_ret_qty
02    Table  02
```

Table1: sale

```
Code  Item   sale_qty
01    Chair  01
02    Table  01
```

I want the result to be like below:

Query result :

```
Code  Item   pur_qty    pur_ret_qty   sale_qty   stock
01    Chair  02         0             1          1
02    Table  03         2             1          0
03    Board  01         0             0          1
```

I want current stock of all items

Comment: Welcome to SO. The expectation is that you will have tried something, and then we will help debug it, rather than just writing the code for you. If you have tried a query, please [edit] your question to show what that was, and how it didn't get the results you wanted.

Comment: Also, it's a good idea to use different scales of numbers for different things, otherwise ids start to look a lot like quantities. And, although it's not a bad start, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @Sandip yes please leaset write what approach did you used to solve your issue.

Comment: Where does the average mentioned in the title come into it?

Answer (score 0):

From your question and expected output, It seems you just need a LEFT join -

```
SELECT P.Code, P.Item, P.pur_qty, PR.pur_ret_qty, S.sale_qty, PR.pur_ret_qty - S.sale_qty
FROM purchase P
LEFT JOIN purchase_return PR ON P.Code = PR.Code
LEFT JOIN sale S ON P.Code = S.Code
```

Presuming, Stock is calculated by Purchase Quantity - Sale Qualtity.

Comment: I am able to calculate stock for individual entry item, but I want to calculate stock sum of or group by item like shown in expected result.